# AOE 2 Windows recorded game on Mac?

Tags: macos, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I owned a PC during my college days and have a whole collection of recorded games (around 1000 games) played during that period. Now I own a mac and would really like to watch those games again, since they bring back happy memories of great times !

Is there a MAC software which allows me to run recorded games of AOE 2 ?

I searched all over the internet and it seems windows recorded AOE 2 games wont run on a MAC.

Is there no way ? :(

Comment: Run a copy of Windows and AOE2 in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)?

Comment: Tried running it using Parallel Desktop, screen used to black out and the game never started up.

Comment: Use an older version of Windows in the VM, perhaps? A 1999 game will want Win95 or WinXP.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right that makes sense. I will definitely try it out !

Comment: AoE 2 runs fine in my Win 7 box.  Some people report color issues which various [patches](http://www.xomicron.com/software/userpatch/) exist to fix.  Parallels might be different, but I don't think it's the Windows version that matters.